# Set Variables like current_user in Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have the following Base Controller for Brands Scope

```
class Brand::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_brands_member!
  before_action :current_company
  helper_method :current_company

  private

  def current_company
    current_brands_member? current_brands_member.company : nil
  end

end
```

The variable `current_brands_member` is the device model for authentication for `members`. Each Member belongs to a `Company`

```
members(id, name, company_id,...)
companies(id, name, ....)
brands(id, name, company_id,...)
```

Since i will be traversing through members to companies to brands i want to set a common variable `current_company` which will have the content of the `member's company` when required in the controllers and views.

When i try to access the same in the controller like this

```
class Brands::MembersController < Brand::ApplicationController
  def index
    puts current_company.inspect
  end
end
```

Am getting the following error

```
undefined local variable or method `current_company' for #<Brands::MembersController:0x007f90c34a8138>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it looks perfectly ok to me.

But there is one thing. In your code in `Brand::AppController` you have a syntax error:

```
def current_company
  # mind the missing space before question mark
  current_brands_member? current_brands_member.company : nil

  # it should be:
  # current_brands_member ? current_brands_member.company : nil

  # or even simpler
  # current_brands_member.try(:company)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `private` methods from outside the class itself. Remove the `private` instruction or move the method outside of it.

Comment: In Ruby `private` prevents you to specify the receiver of the method as it can only be implicit `self`. So the call to `current_company` is perfectly ok in this context.